# Can you print anything in C++, before entering into the main function?

Tags: c++

Can you print anything in C++, before entering into the main function?

It is interview question in Bloomberg:

**Answer** 
:create a global variable assigning value from printf statement with some content.

Comment: You should also ask *them* to show you a) their code style guides, and b) a representable piece of code from their codebase.

Comment: @KerrekSB: as in any big organization (there are > 3000 developers at Bloomberg), the quality of code varies from bad to good. The question about executing code prior to entering `main()` isn't entirely irrelevant and a reasonable intro e.g. to a discussion on how make sure accessed objects are constructed. Does it matter day to day? Probably not. ... and I would be suspicious about the answer quoted above: both global variables and the use of `printf()` would make me wonder.

Answer (score 10):

```
#include <iostream>
struct X
{
   X() 
   {
       std::cout << "Hello before ";
   }
} x;

int main()
{
   std::cout << "main()";
}
```

This well-formed C++ program prints

> Hello before main()

You see, the C++ standard guarantees that the constructors of namespace-scope variables  (in this example, it's `x`) will be executed before `main()`. Therefore, if you print something in a constructor of such an object, it will be printed before `main()`. **QED**

Comment: Answer is missing a piece: How can you be sure std::cout is safe to use at this point?

Comment: @awoodland uhm... Because the standard guarantees it? (tough claim, I will try to prove :)

Comment: 27.4.1/2 in the n3242 draft, I don't have c++03 or n3290 available: *The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first time an object of class ios_base::Init is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins execution. The objects aren't destroyed during program execution. The results of including<iostream> in a translation unit shall be as if <iostream> defined an instance of ios_base::Init with static storage duration. [...]*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas i think you misunderstood what @awoodland is saying. there is no guarantee that `std::cout` will construct before `x`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell I think you misunderstood that quote, it means that the standard *guarantees* that `cout` **will** be constructed before `x`. The order of construction of objects of static duration in a single translation unit is guaranteed to be top to bottom, and that means that the `ios_base::Init` object will be i constructed *before* `x`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas you mean, if `x` is included after io?

Comment: @wilhelmtell I mean in the code in the answer, and yes, only if `x` is *defined* after `iostream` is included, which is the case here, and also in Kerrek's answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & o = (std::cout << "Hello\n");

int main()
{
   o << "Now main() runs.\n";
}
```

Comment: Of course, you don't want `o` to be globally visible: `namespace { std::ostream& o(std::cout << "hello\n"); }` or `static std::ostream& o(std::cout << "hello\n");` but these are details.

Comment: if `operator<<()` throws you have a problem.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: You're basically saying that "if I/O fails and you are required to perform I/O before `main()`, then you have a problem." I agree.

Comment: @wilhelmtell also note that by default iostreams don't throw.

Answer (score 0):

**Header file**

```
class A
{
   static A* a;
public:
   A() { cout << "A" ; }
};
```

**Implementation file:**

```
A* A::a = new A;
```

Well, statics (and not only) are initialized before the call to `main`.

**EDIT**

Another one:

```
bool b = /*(bool)*/printf("before main");

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @wilhelmtell what's wrong with that? `A` can't contain itself as a member, and I was to lazy to write another class to prove a point.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int b() {
  cout << "before ";
  return 0;
}
static int a = b();

int main() {
  cout << "main\n";
}
```