# Is it well-defined behaviour to exit the program before main?

Tags: c++, exit, program-entry-point, undefined-behavior

It's definitely possible to execute code before `main` is called, as seen by many examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439871/can-you-print-anything-in-c-before-entering-into-the-main-function).

However, what if in that pre-main code, the program is told to exit via `std::exit` or `std::abort`? Since `main` is defined as the start of a program, what consequences are there from exiting before the start?

Upon printing something in each section, I get the following results:

***Format:***
**Section**: `output`

**Main**: `main`
**Init (called before main)**: `init`
**Exit (set up with `std::atexit` inside Init)**: `exiting`

***Sample runs:***

**Init called without exiting:**

> init
>   main
>   *returns 0*

**Init calls std::exit(0):**

> init
>   *returns 0*

**Init calls std::abort:**

> init
>   *crashes and returns 3 on Windows with GCC 4.7.2*
>   *crashes and brings up the usual box with VS11*
>   *returns 0 on LiveWorkSpace*

**Init sets handler and calls std::exit(0):**

> init
>   exiting
>   *returns 0*

**Init sets handler and calls std::abort:**

> init
>   *same deal as without the handler*

While searching, I saw this question: [Is there any way a C/C++ program can crash before main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518415/is-there-any-way-a-c-c-program-can-crash-before-main). However, it doesn't answer what I want to know: Is any of this behaviour, calling `std::exit` or `std::abort` before `main`, well-defined? Is any of this undefined behaviour?

Comment: If you're interested in a sample combining the tests, [here's one](http://liveworkspace.org/code/ff19b767d545e3c8a76671b1d21add00).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: there are (almost) no consequences. Some destructors may not be called if you unexpectedly call `exit`, but that's pretty much it.
Generally, not calling destructors is not the cleanest possible way, but then again the end result will be the same.

When a process terminates (via `exit` or `abort` or simply by segfaulting, or another reason), handles (kernel objects, files, etc.) are closed, and the memory associated with the program's address space is reclaimed by the operating system.

There is not much else to it either, because when you call `exit` or `abort`, you're basically requesting that the program terminates (these functions never return!) so you really can't expect anything to happen thereafter.

Note that registering a function like `Init` to be called before `main` is non-standard stuff, but you can get the same effect by having a constructor in a global.

Comment: buffered writes may fail to be written on `exit` due to destructors not being called.

Comment: @JanDvorak: If you refer to "buffered" as in buffered by the C or C++ standard library (iostream or stdio), then yes. But again, this is exactly what you ask for, so it is not surprising. After all, you're saying "that's all, go on and kill me now!". Buffered writes that have been accepted by the operating system will (should) complete successfully, unless the operating system is seriously broken.