# Is there possibility to invoke other methods/instructions before main() when running the code

Tags: c++, invoke, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you print anything in C++, before entering into the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439871/can-you-print-anything-in-c-before-entering-into-the-main-function)

Is there any possibility to run any other instructions before int main() is invoked?

```
int main(){cout<<"a";}
```

and before that call in main() there is call for cout<<"b"; somewhere before. Maybe this #define thing can help.

Comment: `bool f() { cout << "before main"; return true; }

bool dummy = f();

int main(){ cout<<"main"; }`

Comment: Of course there is, google it.

Comment: Yes. In fact, you can even exit the program before `main` :)

Comment: I felt like I was following this right up until *"this #define thing"*. then .. huh?

Comment: @chris, you mean have the process terminated while your code in main is running?  sounds like a bug to me :p

Comment: @thang, I was curious about it, so [I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214661/is-it-well-defined-behaviour-to-exit-the-program-before-main).

Comment: @chris, but that's different from actually having your code running AFTER main.  that's like calling ExitProcess or some OS exit function. once you're done, you're done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a `define`. Just create a global object (in the same file) and its ctor (or anything else you use to initialize it, such as calling a function) will run before main is invoked.

Edit: likewise, those global objects will be destroyed after main exits, so their destructors will run at that time.

Comment: Work great. I will accept it as soon as I can. Is there any possibility to run something after main()?

Comment: @RobertKilar, Destructors.

Answer (score 2):

Global objects are constructed before main() runs. So you can define a class, put your code in its constructor, and then declare a global instance of that class:

```
class temp
{
public:
    temp()
    {
        cout << "before main" << endl;
    }

    ~temp()
    {
       cout << "after main" << endl;
    }
};

temp t;

int main()
{
    cout << "in main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Global variables are also initialized before main() runs.  You can define a function that returns a value, then call that function and assign the value to a global variable in its declaration, like @jrok showed.

Some compilers also support a `#pragma startup` statement to execute a user-defined function at startup (and corresponding `#pragma exit` statement for shutdown):

```
void beforeMain()
{
    cout << "before main" << endl;
}
#pragma startup beforeMain

void afterMain()
{
    cout << "after main" << endl;
}
#pragma exit afterMain

int main()
{
    cout << "in main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just being global does not ensure the object is created/initialized before main executes. It has to be in the same translation unit as main to ensure it's created before main is invoked.