# Is there possibility to invoke other methods/instructions AFTER main() when running the code

Tags: c++, invoke, program-entry-point

Is there any possibility to run any other instructions after int main() is invoked?

```
int main(){cout<<"a";}
```

and after that call in main() there is call for cout<<"b"; somewhere after. No change int `main()`whatsoever.

Comment: A most-fitting followup to [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651731/is-there-possibility-to-invoke-other-methods-instructions-before-main-when-run).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Destructors of static objects, and functions registered with [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit), are executed after `main` exits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct S {~S() {std::cout << "c";}};
void f() {std::cout << "b";}

S s;

int main() {
    std::atexit(f);
    std::cout << "a";
}
```

Output: abc

Answer (score 6):

You could put your last part in [**`atexit()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/).
It will run on program termination, i.e. after your call to main() is completed.

You could have multiple `atexit`s as well.

> If more than one atexit function has been specified by different calls
>   to this function, they are all executed in reverse order as a stack
>   (i.e. the last function specified is the first to be executed at
>   exit).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, define a class that does `cout << "b"` in its destructor, and then define a global instance of that class.

Answer (score 2):

In short, very little option. You can use `atexit()` to make something happen after main exits, or you can have a global object whose destructor is called after main exits. But the end of main is officially the end of your program.