# printing something before and after main() in c/c++

Tags: c++

Consider the code snippet

```
main()
{
  cout << "Hello";
}
```

Without touching the above code snippet print

Hi
Hello
Bye

Comment: Could you write what the question is, please?

Comment: [Can you print anything in C++, before entering into the main function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439871/can-you-print-anything-in-c-before-entering-into-the-main-function), [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0b53f9103c0f989)

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adobe-interview-set-12-campus-mts-1/

3. Round 1 PI
g. Consider the code snippet

main()
{
  cout << "Hello";
} 

Without touching the above code snippet print
Hi
Hello
Bye

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    A() { cout << "Hi" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << endl << "Bye"; }
};

A a;

main()
{
  cout << "Hello";
}
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/vG0Kqj)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() { cout << "Hi" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "\nBye" << endl; }
};

A a;


int

// untouched part :)
main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

The output is

```
Hi
Hello
Bye
```

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Why is it too late when it is the only valid code?!

Comment: Apparently the OP has changed the output he wanted originally (there were no linefeeds).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ The absence of the line feed is the only one defect. The other defect is the absence of return type of main. So only my answer is correct.